# Drawing a text using static layout, draws the text outside of the specific rectangle in android using canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-paint

I want to draw a text in a rectangle of specific size, but the result i m getting is not satisfactory.

Here is the code i have tried  till now:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mCanvas = canvas;
    parentRect = new Rect();
    mCanvas.getClipBounds(parentRect);
    maxLeft = parentRect.left;
    maxTop = parentRect.top;
    maxRight = parentRect.right;
    maxBottom = parentRect.bottom;

    // custom drawing code here
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    // make the entire canvas white
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);

    String txt = getContext().getString(R.string.txt_graphics_rotation);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(50);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

    rect = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(txt, 0, txt.length(), rect);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER));

    Log.e(TAG, "onDraw: rect : " + rect.left + " : " + rect.top + " : " + rect.right + " : " + rect.bottom);
    Paint paint1 = new Paint();
    paint1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint1.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    canvas.save();

    TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
    textPaint.set(paint);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        StaticLayout staticLayout = StaticLayout.Builder
                .obtain(txt, 0, txt.length(), textPaint, parentRect.width())
                .setBreakStrategy(Layout.BREAK_STRATEGY_BALANCED)
                .setAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
                .setIncludePad(true)
                .build();
        if (staticLayout.getLineCount() == 1) {
            widthOfText = textPaint.measureText(txt);
            heightOfText = -textPaint.ascent() + textPaint.descent();
        } else {
            widthOfText = staticLayout.getWidth();
            heightOfText = (staticLayout.getHeight());
        }

        canvas.translate(widthOfText / 2, heightOfText / 2);
        staticLayout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, widthOfText, heightOfText, paint1);
        canvas.restore();
    } else {
        canvas.drawText(txt, rect.left, rect.top / 2, paint);
        widthOfText = paint.measureText(txt) / 2;
        heightOfText = rect.height();
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

Here i am getting the rectangle and text in different position, but i want to merge them.

Note : i know i have not followed the best practice, please ignore it for now.

Comment: merge them? how? any image with explanation?

Comment: i mean want to write text inside rectangle. For now i m able to draw rectangle and text on canvas, but both are at different position.

Comment: so use `canvas.translate()` then `layout.draw(canvas)` then `canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height)`

Comment: @pskink thanks for you effort but still its not completely done. My half text is outside the rectangle.

Comment: then dont scale the canvas

Comment: Still its same. Also my rectangle bounds are 3 : -37 : 404 : 10 left, top, right bottom respectively

Comment: ok again: call canvas.translate(100, 200) then layout.draw(canvas) then canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height) where width is layout's width and height is layout's height - what do you see?

Comment: tried but its not working. is there any way of getting the text bounds in static layout?

Comment: post your code then (with what you tried the last time)

Comment: updated the code..please check

Comment: you did not do what i said, i said [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/mSjFf7NJ)

Comment: its not working.

Comment: the code you provided in link. Can you edit in my code snippet if possible?

Comment: what is not working? do you see a text with multiple lines surrounded by a red frame? if not, what do you see then?

Comment: yes i do see the thing you mentioned, but how to achieve it for dynamically that i dont understand, i cant give fix size to any of the view

Comment: so is it working or not? what "dynamically" do you mean? what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: The code you provide is working. What i want to do is implement zoom and drag functionality along with bounding text to the specific rectangle

Comment: i have no idea what you mean